# display items, it is only available between the datetime1 and datetime2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am developing one sample application in PHP and Mysql, but i am facing one problem.

In My application user will fill the inputs `$work_starts_date_and_time` and `$work_End_Date_and_time`.

i am storing both the inputs in a database

```
work_starts_date_and_time 
work_End_Date_and_time
```

now, when user fill the inputs, if the resourse is free in between the `work_starts_date_and_time` and `work_End_Date_and_time` then only it should visible to the user. if that resource is allocated to other user it should not visible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  How do you know if a resource is free or not, for instance?

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: For example, now i have 3 resources,  user1 will book Resource1 from 05-12-2016 10.00AM to 05-12-2016 06-00PM. Now if User2 will select the date 05-12-2016 11.00AM the Resource1 should not come, the rest of the resources should visible to User2

Comment: Have you got any code you've tried?

Comment: Wrap the code statements with the back tick ` so that they can appear readable and nicer. By the way, the code you've provided here doesn't seem to be relative to the question.

Comment: Thanks, finally i got the code, it's working fine